# Python & API user input

Tags: python, api, input, syntax

My code is

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint

from pip._vendor.distlib.compat import raw_input

recipe_ingredients = input("What is the recipe ingredients? ")
number_recipes = input("How many recipes do you want? ")
url = 'https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/findByIngredients?ingredients={}&number={}&'.format(recipe_ingredients,number_recipes)

response = requests.get(url)
print(response)
```

However, when I am inputting more than one ingredient in the format of (two ingredients) cheese **and** potato it is returning results for either the first variable or tells me there is a syntax error with **and**.

Is there any way I am able to program my search function to accept **and** ,whereby it can display all the results for both words, as it is likely a user will put 'and' within their search for more than one ingredient.

( I am using pycharm btw)

Comment: Please provide an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or it's hard to understand what you're asking. It sounds like you're putting in "and" outside of a string, in which case Python will interpret it as the keyword "and" for boolean operations

Comment: @ch4rl1e97, python will not interpret `"and"` string as the keyword `and`.

Comment: Not what I meant @HarshalParekh My point was `and` and `"and"` are two separate things to Python. Thus I said "it sounds like you're putting in and *outside* of a string.."

Answer (score 0):

You are only requesting one string from the user. Whenever you try to enter 2 strings separated by `Enter`, the second string cannot be saved and thus the exception.

You may fix it like:

```
n = int(input("Number of ingredients: "))
recipe_ingredients = []

print("Enter " + str(n) + " recipe ingredients")

for i in range(n):
    recipe_ingredients.append(input())
```